# Suppose a homogeneous triangle with mass $M$ is in equilibrium hanging by 3 strings from its vertices the ceiling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

> Suppose a homogeneous triangle with mass $M$ is in equilibrium hanging by 3 strings from its vertices the ceiling; show that the tension of each string is proportional to its length.

[Here is what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAy5q.jpg), and I'm almost sure that this leads to a solution. However I don't know how to proceed. Also, I'd like to know if there was a more elegant solution. Any help is appreciated, but I prefer tips and insights rather than full solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please try not to post formulae as images, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for hints, I will just give some insights:

a) You need not deal with breaking them to $X,Y,Z$ components. If a proof of a general statement is asked, most of the time it can be done with abstract vectors.

b) If you chose the common point of the 3 strings on the ceiling as origin, calculations will be a lot more easier to do, as you get both the position vectors of the 3 vertices and the directions of the 3 tension forces at the same time. (since it can only act along the string)

> c) For this question you will need to prove that the position vector of the centroid is also along direction of gravity (i.e. vertically downward.)

> d)You will need to use scalar triple product for this one, if you don't know this beforehand, [here is the introduction for it](https://onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/multiply2/) which is good enough for this question.

> e) Like lami's theorem there is a similar concept for 4 vectors which is an key idea to use in equilibrium related questions, [here is the concept](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163033/extension-of-lamis-theorem).

if you still need help in solving the question, [here is the solution](https://prnt.sc/104epyy)